# How to exclude certain actions from login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, controller

Using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.2.13, I have an admin "section" which has a `BaseController`. I want to restrict almost all pages to logged-in users only. The only pages that non-logged-in users can see are login, forgot password, etc. Currently I am just keeping a list of controllers and actions which are "open" but I'm thinking there's a better way.

```
class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController
  @@non_authorized_paths = [
    { :controller => "admin/account" , :actions => [ "login", "login_post", "logout", "forgot_password", "forgot_password_post", "reset_password", "reset_password_post" ]}
  ]

  layout "admin/layouts/admin"
  before_filter :authorized?

  def authorized?
    if (session[:user] != nil || @@non_authorized_paths.any? {|o| o[:controller] == params[:controller] && o[:actions].any? { |a| a == params[:action] } })
      return
    end

    flash[:warning] = "You should login before doing that."
    redirect_to :controller => "admin/account", :action => "login"
  end
end
```

Basically if the user is already authenticated or the controller/action they're accessing is in the list of `@@non_authorized_paths`, then no redirecting occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
before_filter :authorized?, :except => ['login', 'login_post', 'logout', etc.]
```

Are these actions in a sessions_controller? you should be able to add the before filter to that class, have it `skip_before_filter` on the actions you care about.  You can use `:only` or `:except` to keep the list short.